# How to have the intallation file actually work

Tags: software-installation

I've never even been able to get Ubuntu to work . . . and I've tried multiple times. Current iteration: won't run as its own program (always wants to copy to a disc), won't copy to a disc (speaking of Ubuntu glitches, the file is TOO BIG FOR A DISC), and if I zip file it, it fits on a disc but won't run. Yes, the Windows tax is  a necessary evil.

Comment: If you don't have a DVD or USB medium large enough for the full desktop ISO file, you can [install from a minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) instead. For general help with verifying and burning ISO images see the [BurningIsoHowto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

Comment: @steeldriver You might want to post something like that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

- The regular Ubuntu installer needs to be burned to a writeable DVD, because it is too big to fit on a CD.
- If you cannot write to DVDs, you can alternatively write it to a USB stick.  There are official instructions [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows).

You also have the option of installing from the "minimal CD installer" as mentioned in one of the comments, but I would not recommend you do that unless you have to, because that installer is not as user-friendly.